# java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.transactionType" When running a test

Tags: java

I am creating a Rest API with a simple CRUD, but I am getting the error below when trying to test the findById method.

Follow the error.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.transactionType" 
Expected :EXPENSE
Actual   :EXPENSE
```

And this is the code snippet

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "test@test", roles = {"USER", "ADMIN"})
public void findByIdAndUserShouldReturnTransaction() throws Exception {

    // given
    TransactionResponse response = new TransactionResponse(2L, "transaction_2", TransactionType.EXPENSE, BigDecimal.TEN, LocalDate.now());

    // when
    when(service.findByIdAndUser(anyLong())).thenReturn(response);

    // then
    this.mockMvc
            .perform(get("/api/v1/transactions/{id}", 2L))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value(response.getName()))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.amount").value(response.getAmount()))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.transactionType").value(response.getTransactionType()))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.paymentDate").value(response.getPaymentDate()));
    verify(service, times(1)).findByIdAndUser(2L);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(service);


}
```

I hope you can help me!

Comment: can you add snippet code for `findByIdAndUser`?

Comment: What are the return types? I.e., if you will try to compare ENUM EXPENSE & STRING EXPENSE, you will get assertion error

Comment: The returns that I believe are causing the error are two, one type enum, and also a LocalDate.

Comment: I'm with @Alex here: the get request will return a JSON string and JSON does not support enum constants. Commonly enum constants are represented by their name when serialized as JSON. And `"EXPENSE"` does not equal `TransactionType.EXPENSE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON cannot store enums directly. When enum values are serialized to JSON they are represented by their name. `"EXPENSE"` is not equal to `TransactionType.EXPENSE` (but it is to `TransctionType.EXPENSE.name()`).

This should work:

```
this.mockMvc
        .perform(get("/api/v1/transactions/{id}", 2L))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        ...
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.transactionType").value(response.getTransactionType().name()))
        ...;
```

By the way, what is your test supposed to test? It looks like it is only testing Mockito's ability to mock a service call. Your service call is mocked and its result directly returned. You then verify that the values are equal to the mocked values set a few lines before. Are you sure you are testing the right thing?